# JPA typed Query passing values in a Map in constructor

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

In JPQL `TypedQuery` we can select values and directly pass values in other class's construtor. That is working fine. I want those selected record in a key value paired map so that I can pass the whole map in variable argument construtor and assign its values from class property name from map (by getting values from its property name). Is there any way to achieve this?

Here is my query:

```
hqlQuery.append("select new mypackage.Myclass( new map('employeeCode',he.employeeCode) , new map('resignationID',he.employeeId))");

MyClass{
    private String employeeCode;
    private Integer employeeId;
    public MyClass(Map<String, Object>... maps) //Variable map
    {
        super();
        for (Map<String, Object> map : maps) {
            if (map.containsKey("employeeId")) {
                this.employeeId= (Integer) map.get("employeeId");
            }
            if (map.containsKey("employeeCode")) {
                this.employeeCode = (String) map.get("employeeCode");
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to do this so that i dont have to remember the construtor argument order in case when there are so many attribute of a class.

when i am creating query i am getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: new near line 1, column 70 [select new com.talentpact.businessobject.resignation.ResignationTO(  new map('resignationID',resignation.resignationId)  ) from com.talentpact.model.HrEmployeeResignation resignation   join  resignation.hrEmployee he   left join  resignation.expectedRelievingDateId where resignation.resignationId=:resignationId ]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:276)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1537)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:295)
    ... 165 more
```

Comment: simple reading of the JPA spec says there is no such "map(blah blah)" in JPQL.

Comment: http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.1.1/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_select_clause :
I was thinking if new keword instantiate new instance of an object why not pass new instance in the constructor also ; i have tried fully qualified name also java.util.Map ;; is there any solution for my query.